# Custom directive using comprehension expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I spend a lot of time in Python so I really like the `comprehension_expression` syntax in Angular's [ngOptions](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/ng.directive%3aselect).

But I would like to use this syntax in other inputs, like with an [`ng-list`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/ng.directive%3angList).
For example, I have a non-trivial list of `slug` objects:

```
$scope.slugs = [
  {id:  1, name: 'angular-directives'},
  {id: 23, name: 'composing-your-very-own-angular-directives'},
  {id: 70, name: 'directives-in-angular-js'},
];
```

And I would like to edit the names with a single input, creating plain objects with only a name property for new slugs. However, `<input ng-list ng-model="slug.name for slug in slugs">` doesn't work.

Since the out-of-the-box syntax doesn't work (and I wouldn't really expect it to), how can I use the `comprehension_expression` syntax in the scope of a custom directive?

Answer (score 0):

NgModel directive binds element to a property on the scope, it doesn't support comprehension expression. You need to create a array which contains all name value in slugs if want to edit name in a input field by using "ng-list".

And then create a "newSlugs" array to collect the object with new name. Refresh the name once the object has been updated by registering a $watch observer to every slug.

```
$scope.slugs=[{id:1,name:'angular-directives'},{id:23,name:'composing-your-very-own-angular-directives'},{id:70, name:'directives-in-angular-js'}];
$scope.names=[];  //for ng-list
$scope.newSlugs = [];  

//loop through every element in array slugs
$scope.slugs.forEach(function(ele,index,array){
    //for ng-list
    $scope.names.push(ele.name);
    //create a new obj with one attribute 'name'
    $scope.newSlugs.push({name:ele.name});
    //register observer to every slug, update the name of obj in newSlugs once user had updated the name
    $scope.$watch("names["+index+"]",function(newValue,oldValue){
        $scope.slugs[index].name=newValue;
        $scope.newSlugs[index].name=newValue;
    });
});
```

BTW, it's a "update" function... I think maybe you need to prevent user from creating a new name by inserting splitter character.

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NTmt/3/).

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: I realize that my optimistic abuse of `ng-model` doesn't fit into how `ng-model` is generally used, but I'm open to use of comprehension expressions in other attributes, for the purpose of linking scope. I don't see what you're getting at with `newSlugs` in your example, though -- when will that ever differ from `slugs`? Also, I do want to create new slugs on the fly, not just update existing ones, which will be synced dynamically based on whether or not they have an `{id: ?, ...}` property.